# Is it possible to replace 14.04 LTS with 16.04 LTS remotely?

Tags: 14.04, server, 16.04, remote

As the title says, I have a 14.04 server that I don't mind formatting and want to replace with 16.04.  However, I don't want to drive to the datacenter to plop a cd into the drive.  Is it possible to prepare a headless/no prompt image to install on reboot?  I do have access to IPMI 1.5.

I don't want to 'upgrade' 14.04, I want a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. `do-release-upgrade -m server`. You can use screen, so you can connect to the running process, when you have a dc

Comment: Won't this upgrade the system though?  Also, wouldn't I have to wait until 16.04.1 before the upgrade is available?

Comment: @Brian why shouldn't it be available, before 16.04.1 releases?

Comment: I upgraded my Ubuntu 15.10 server this way a week ago

Comment: Because historically, upgrades to LTS haven't been available until the first bug fix release.  I don't believe it applies to non LTS upgrades, so your upgrade worked fine.  Either way, I don't want to upgrade I want a clean install, as indicated in my question. @motte001

Comment: @Brian I saw this in the Release Notes: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/#OpenSSH_7.2p2